# how to get deep nested json from a query on self relation table in prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, prisma

i want to create a deep nested menu dynamically with prisma ORM and get all menus with sub menus as a deeply nested json object
this is my code and i already try a query to but the result is not what i want

***this is my prismaSchema file***

```
model Menu {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  title         String
  url           String @default("#")
  parentMenu    Menu?  @relation("parentSubCategory", fields: [parrentMenuId], references: [id])
  subMenu       Menu[] @relation("parentSubCategory")
  parrentMenuId Int?
}
```

i want a query to get a json with deep nested menus and submenus like below

```
 {
     title:"menu1",
     subMenu:[
       {
         title:"sub1"
         subMenus:[
          {
           title:"sub3",
           subMenus:[
           {
             title:"sub4"
           }
         ]
         } 
       ]  
    }
   ]
    }
```

I already try query below but the result is not wat i want

```
const result = await prisma.menu.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      url: true,
      subMenu: true,
    },
  });
```

**result of my query is like this**

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sample",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "digital",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "digital",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "pc & laptop",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "pc & laptop",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": "pc",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "title": "laptop",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "pc",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": "pc parts",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "laptop",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": []
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "title": "pc parts",
      "url": "#",
      "subMenu": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "title": "ram and storage",
          "url": "#",
          "parrentMenuId": 6
        }
      ]
    },
```

can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Just add as many as sub-menus as present in that table in this nested structure.

```js
const result = await prisma.menu.findMany({
        select: {
          id: true,
          title: true,
          url: true,
          subMenu: { //first-sub menu
            id: true,
            title: true,
            url: true,
            subMenu: { //2nd one
              id: true,
              title: true,
              url: true,
              subMenu: { // 3rd one
                id: true,
                title: true,
                url: true,
                subMenu: true // Presumably the last sub menu
              }
            }
          },
        },
      });
```

Comment: can this be used to get an infinite level of sub menus?